# Back button is not working on drilldown pie chart

Tags: angularjs, laravel, highcharts, arcgis

Here, I am using highcharts library for creating drilldown pie chart, I have used click event for filtering and drillup for revert filtering but it is not working for me anybody check it for me..?

Here have shared some of my code :

**Create Chart Function**

```
createChart(chartData) {

    this.chartData = chartData;
    let currencySign = this.currencySign;

    let options = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie',
            // backgroundColor: bgColor
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {}
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Plant Types",
            id: "plant_types",
            data: chartData.series
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                let title = this.series.name;
                if(title == 'Products') {
                    title += " ("+ this.point['rate_unit'] + ")";
                }

                let pointcolor = this.point.color;
                let pointName = this.point.name;
                let pointY = numeral(this.point.y).format('0,0');
                let pointPercentage = numeral(this.point.percentage).format('0,0.00');
                let pointTotal = numeral(this.point.total).format('0,0');
                return '<span style="font-size:11px">'+title+'</span><br><span style="color:'+pointcolor+'">'+pointName+':</span> '+currencySign+'' + pointY +'<b>('+pointPercentage+'%)</b><br/>Total: '+currencySign+''+pointTotal;
            }
        },
        drilldown: {
            series: []
        }
    };

    options['plotOptions']['pie']['events'] = this.chartClickHandler();

    // set theme options if dark theme enabled.
    if(this._localStorageService.getIsDarkTheme()) {
        Highcharts['theme'] =  this._chartThemeOptions.getSearchScreenDarkThemeOptions();
        Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts['theme']);
    }

    this.chart = new Chart(options);
}
```

**Event Handler Method**

```
chartClickHandler() {

    let clickObj = {
        click: (e) => {

            let userOptions = e.point.series.userOptions;
            let key = "";

            if(userOptions['id'] == "plant_types") {
                this.chart.ref.showLoading('Loading Technologies...');
                this.loadTechnologyByPlantType(e.point);
                key = "plant_plant_type";

            } else if (userOptions['id'] == "technologies") {
                this.chart.ref.showLoading('Loading Prime Movers...');
                this.loadPrimeMoversByTechnologies(e.point);
                key = "generator_technology";

            } else if (userOptions['id'] == 'prime_movers') {
                let nameArr = (e.point.name).split(' - ');
                let primeMoverCode = nameArr[0];
                key = "prime_mover";
            }

            let filterData = {
                type: key,
                selectedValues: e.point.name
            };

            this.onSelectFilter.emit(filterData);
        },

        drillUp: (e) => {
            console.log("revert event");
        }
    };

    return clickObj;
}
```

if drillup event is not using for revert then which event is used for revert any suggestion?

Comment: You don't seem to use the [drilldown event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown) then I don't think the drillUp will trigger.

Comment: @Core972 - is it necessary to use drillDown event for using drillUp event?

Comment: I don't know how `chartData.series` is defined. The drilldown need to be identified in the serie like in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/) line 47 `drilldown: "Chrome"` and then defined line 82.

Comment: Hello @Priyanka khullar, Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve? Also, some minimal live example would be very useful, you can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9k0amLbg/